# LESS mixin for "Calc" values

Tags: less

I would like to write a LESS mixin to easy insert `calc` values

```
.calc-mixin(@property, @operation)     
{
  @{property}: -webkit-calc(@operation);
  @{property}:    -moz-calc(@operation);
  @{property}:         calc(@operation);
}

.a {
  .calc-mixin(width,'100% + 2px');
}
```

This is not a valid CSS because its output is:

```
.a {
  width: -webkit-calc('100% + 2px');
  width: -moz-calc('100% + 2px');
  width: calc('100% + 2px');
}
```

Please, how to remove " `''` " characters in final output?

Comment: Have you tried `.calc-mixin(width,~'100% + 2px');`?

Comment: Effectively.... could be a solution. Not so inutitive for end user like possibility to fix it directly in mixin declaration instead in mixin call but.... maybe acceptable :-)

Comment: Would `@{property}:         calc(e(@operation));` maybe work?

Comment: wow, I did not know this solution, perfect!!! If you make your comment an answer, I'll surely accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CSS escape](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) function like this:

```
@{property}: calc(e(@operation));
```